# jQuery document ready execution order differences between 1.3.2 and 1.10.2

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently, I am going to upgrade jQuery library from 1.3.2 to 1.10.2 in existing website ( The website wrote since 2008 ).
But due to legacy issues, the following code pattern used very often and it is not possible to rewrite or review all.

```
function AgainAlert() {
    alert('again');
}
function Test_init() {
    alert('before');
    $(document).ready(AgainAlert);

    alert('after');
}

$(document).ready(Test_init);
```

After upgraded it, found there is timing issue due to the execution order of document ready.
The execution results of the above code using jQuery 1.3.2 is

1. before
2. again
3. after

**The code sample jQuery 1.3.2 :** http://jsfiddle.net/w4T7b/

While result order by using jQuery 1.10.1 is

1. before
2. after
3. again

**The code sample jQuery 1.10.1 :** http://jsfiddle.net/FGt54/

Does anyone have any idea of this problem? **( I must keep the code pattern as above )**

Also, it is possible solve this issue or workaround?

Comment: This behavior is interesting, but you shouldn't really call `ready` twice.

Comment: The best solution is to call `AgainAlert` directly. PS: I just realized your name is Derek too.

Comment: Hi Derek 朕會功夫. Yes, it should not call the ready twice, but due to legacy issues, I have no choice. There are too much :(

Comment: I was thinking if you can move some of the codes inside jQuery 1.3.2 to 1.10.1, however the difference in their structures are too big and there's no way it is possible. Therefore, remove all the repetitive `.ready` seems to me is the only solution.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @Derek Then I think you should refactor your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function AgainAlert() {
    alert('again');
}
function Test_init() {
    alert('before');
    AgainAlert();

    alert('after');
}

$(document).ready(Test_init);
```

By changing `$(document).ready(AgainAlert);` to simply `AgainAlert();` works great, it already is inside a `$.ready()`, no need to wrap it again.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FGt54/2/)

EDIT:
What you can do, is override the jQuery `$.ready` event so that it will only wait for the body to be ready the first time it is called, and the rest will simply run the function.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to change

```
$(document).ready(AgainAlert);
```

to

```
AgainAlert();
```

because the first `.ready` already assures you the DOM is loaded and there is no need for another one.

---

One other way to get around is to modify `.ready`

By adding

```
$.fn.ready = function(a){ a(); };
```

to `Test_init` will fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/FGt54/3/